# Convert Database object into database URL string

Tags: 7, drush, uri, database

I've define my own database connection in my Drupal settings file as follow:

```
$databases['migrate']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'drupal',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => 'root',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'prefix' => '',
);
```

To read that in [Database object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/class/Database/7) format, you can run:

```
drush eval 'print_r(Database::getConnectionInfo("default", "migrate"));'
```

And now I would like to have the string representation (similar to [$db_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/db_url/6) in Drupal 6) to use it in some drush commands on that database e.g. `drush --db-url=${DB_URL} status`.

So I would like to convert above Database array format into database URL string format (e.g. `mysql://root:root@localhost/drupal`).

Is there any easy way of doing that via function, PHP code or drush?

---

Additional info:

- There is [update_parse_db_url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!update.inc/function/update_parse_db_url/7) function, but it's converting database connection URLs and return D7 compatible array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Drush:

```
drush sa @site --with-db-url
```

Or, to isolate just the db-url:

```
drush sa @site --with-db-url --format=csv --fields=db-url --field-labels=0
```

Comment: 2 questions: 1) what version of Drush does the 2nd work it, its failing in 5.8 with unknown options (all after --with-db-url).  2) it looks like this solution will only work for sites you defined site-aliases for ?

Comment: 1) The second example is for Drush 6.  Drush 6 stable was released on 15 August; not many fixes are being backported to Drush 5 any more, so folks should upgrade. 2) drush sa will look up the database connection from settings.php if it's not defined in the alias.  If the alias is remote, try `drush @remote sa @self --with-db-url`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one-liner:

```
drush eval '$db = Database::getConnection("default", "migrate")->getConnectionOptions();  echo $db["driver"] . "://" . $db["username"] . ":" . $db["password"] . "@" . $db["host"] . ":" . $db["port"] . "/" . $db["database"];'
```

---

For the long-term solution, this can be achieved by defining drush command in your module (foo.drush.inc):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_drush_command().
 */
function foo_drush_command() {
  $items = array();
  $items['get-db-uri'] = array(
    'callback'  => 'foo_drush_get_db_uri',
    'arguments' => array(
      'name' => array(
        'description' => dt('Database name.'),
        'required'    => TRUE,
      ),
      'key' => array(
        'description' => dt('Key.'),
        'required'    => TRUEs,
      ),
    ),
    'description' => dt('Returns database URI for a specified name and key.'),
    'examples' => array(
      'drush get-db-uri migrate default' => dt('Will return db uri in format: driver://user:pass@host:port/dbname'),
    ),
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_drush_help().
 */
function foo_drush_help($section) {
  switch ($section) {
    case 'get-db-uri':
      return dt("Returns database URI.");
  }
}

/**
 * Drush command (get-db-uri).
 *
 * Returns database URI for a specified name and key.
 *
 * @param string $name
 *   Database name.
 * @param string $key
 *   Key.
 */
function foo_drush_get_db_uri($name, $key) {
  $connection = Database::getConnection($key, $name);
  $info       = $connection->getConnectionOptions();

  echo $info['driver'] . '://' . $info['username'] . ':' . $info['password'] . '@' . $info['host'] . ':' . $info['port'] . '/' . $info['database'];
}
```

Example usage:

```
drush get-db-uri migrate default
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have bootstrapped drupal instance, drush and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed

```
drush status --fields="db-driver,db-hostname,db-port,db-username,db-password,db-name" --format="json" | jq '."db-driver"+"://"+."db-username"+":"+."db-password"+"@"+."db-hostname"+":"+."db-port"+"/"+."db-name"'
```